# Adventure Story Graph Tuple Bug

Tags: python, tuples, graph-theory

I'm working on a practice project dealing with graphs. It's an interactive adventure game where the user inputs choices and tries to escape the wilderness, however, right now, when the user chooses an answer for the first prompt, it ends the game without prompting the other choices to make the game go on longer and make more sense to the user. I used tuples to represent a branching narrative, but I think I'm using it incorrectly. If anyone has a second to look through this or has any tips, I would greatly appreciate it!!

Here's the main.py file that creates the root node of the story tree and initiates the game:

```py
# Import TreeNode class and story_data from respective files
from story_data import story_data
from tree_node import TreeNode

def main():
    # Create the root node with the initial story piece
    story_root = TreeNode(story_data.story_piece, story_data.choices)

    # Print the initial story piece
    print("Once upon a time...")
    print(story_root.story_piece)

    # Begin the story traversal
    story_root.traverse()

# Check if this file is being run directly
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here's the tree_node.py file that represents nodes in the story tree:

```py
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, story_piece, choices=None):
        self.story_piece = story_piece
        self.choices = choices or []

    def add_child(self, node):
        self.choices.append(node)

    def traverse(self):
        story_node = self
        while story_node.choices:
            choice = input("Enter 1 or 2 to continue the story: ")
            if choice not in ["1", "2"]:
                print("Invalid choice. Try again.")
            else:
                chosen_index = int(choice) - 1
                chosen_child = story_node.choices[chosen_index]
                print(chosen_child.story_piece)
                story_node = chosen_child
```

And lastly, here's the story_data.py file that defines the structure of the story, creating instances of the tree node to represent different parts of the story:

```
from tree_node import TreeNode

story_data = TreeNode("""
You are in a forest clearing. There is a path to the left.
A bear emerges from the trees and roars!
Do you: 
1 ) Roar back!
2 ) Run to the left...
""")

choice_a_1 = TreeNode("""
The bear returns and tells you it's been a rough week. After 
making peace with
a talking bear, he shows you the way out of the forest.

YOU HAVE ESCAPED THE WILDERNESS.
""")

choice_a_2 = TreeNode("""
The bear returns and tells you that bullying is not okay before 
leaving you alone
in the wilderness.

YOU REMAIN LOST.
""")

choice_b_1 = TreeNode("""
The bear is unamused. After smelling the flowers, it turns 
around and leaves you alone.

YOU REMAIN LOST.
"""
)
choice_b_2 = TreeNode("""
The bear understands and apologizes for startling you. Your new 
friend shows you a 
path leading out of the forest.

YOU HAVE ESCAPED THE WILDERNESS.
"""
)

story_data.add_child(choice_a_1)
story_data.add_child(choice_a_2)
story_data.add_child(choice_b_1)
story_data.add_child(choice_b_2)
```

Comment: Thanks @mkrieger1, I've added the code to my issue.

Comment: You have only added child nodes to `story_data`. None of the other nodes contain child nodes, so the `while` loop quits.

Comment: What, specifically should the program do instead of stopping? What graph of `TreeNode` items should the program traverse?

Comment: Thanks @quamrana! You were right, I had to add more child nodes to choices and instead of using it as a graph with tuples, I just used instances of the `TreeNode` for the choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as stated in the comments,

> You have only added child nodes to `story_data`. None of the other nodes contain child nodes, so the `while` loop quits.

To give a bit more detail, after executing the code in `story_data.py`

the `TreeNode`s look like this:

```py
story_data.story_piece = "You are in a forest [..]"
story_data.choices = [choice_a_1, choice_a_2, choice_b_1, choice_b_2]

choice_a_1.story_piece = "The bear [..] tells you it's been a rough week [..]"
choice_a_1.choices = []

choice_a_2.story_piece = "The bear [..] tells you bully is not okay [..]"
choice_a_2.choices = []

choice_b_1.story_piece = "The bear is unamused [..]"
choice_b_1.choices = []

choice_b_2.story_piece = "The bear understands [..]"
choice_b_2.choices = []
```

The first iteration of the `while` loop works because the conditional, `story_node.choices`, finds a non-empty `list` which evaluates to `True`.

When the user chooses a value from `["1","2"]`, they are effectively choosing between `choice_a_1` and `choice_a_2`. For both of these, `story_node.choices` will be an empty `list`, which evaluates as `False`, ending the loop without a second iteration.

If you're ever unsure about a python program's behavior, you can always debug it with an IDE like VS Code/PyCharm/etc., or use `print` statements right before and/or after wherever your suspect the problem is.

So in this case, try running the program with the following change:

```py
class TreeNode:
    # .. (unchanged)

    def traverse(self):
        story_node = self
        while story_node.choices:
            print("story_node.choices before choice " + story_node.choices) #  <-- added
            choice = input("Enter 1 or 2 to continue the story: ")
            if choice not in ["1", "2"]:
                print("Invalid choice. Try again.")
            else:
                chosen_index = int(choice) - 1
                chosen_child = story_node.choices[chosen_index]
                print(chosen_child.story_piece)
                story_node = chosen_child
                print("story_node.choices after choice " + story_node.choices) #  <-- added

    def __repr__(self):          # <-- added
        return self.story_piece  # <-- added
```

With this you would get something like the following output:

```
Once upon a time...
1) [..]
2) [..]

story_node.choices before choice  [
The bear returns and tells you it's been a rough week. [..]
, 
The bear returns and tells you that bullying is not okay [..]
, 
The bear is unamused. [..]
, 
The bear understands and apologizes [..]
]
Enter 1 or 2 to continue the story: 1

The bear returns and tells you it's been a rough week. [..]

story_node.choices after choice  []
```

notice the last line of output is an empty `list`, which is likely leading to the behavior you mention.

---

As an aside, `["1", "2"]` is semantically a `list`, a `tuple` would look like `("1", "2")`, but the behavior is identical in this instance as there are no assignments or hashing, [you can read a bit about differences](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#immutable-sequence-types))

You may also want to check out the [`visitor` design pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/visitor) as it would let you move your processing of each `TreeNode` outside the object itself, since after the first iteration, there's no reason for the `traverse` method to be inside `TreeNode`. Example [here](https://gist.github.com/mxndtaylor/06ffc7fbf843a458f597227758d7fa71)

Comment: Wow, thank you @mxt for taking the time to explain all of that to me. I see now how the error was occurring. Instead of using the graph, i just used instances of the `TreeNode` to make the branching for responses flow better with the added child nodes for choices..if you want to check out what I changed, you can find it here : https://github.com/Sk-223/Adventure_Game.git 

Thanks again for being so helpful, I really do appreciate your time!